# Customtkinter button text wrapping (doesn't support wraplength attribute)

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm using the customtkinter library to create a rounded button with an outline, this button can contain a variable length of text and the button itself should dynamically resize.

There is no `wraplength` attribute for customtkinter so I can't just do something like `self.configure(wraplength = self.winfo_width())` as that will return an error telling me that it does not support wraplength.

One solution I've come up with is making a customtkinter frame (so I can retain the rounded edges) and binding all of the hover and click events to it, then inserting a tk.label inside of it which will then have the wrapping.

Comment: Please post an attempt to implement one of your solutions.

Comment: @СергейКох Hi, I tried to implement that in, I posted here first just in case there was a solution much simpler and easier than redesigning the entire thing to a frame.

So I tried doing that, it ended up not working. For some reason as soon as I hover over the frame the frame things I started hovering and instantly thinks I stopped even though I'm still hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently CustomTk does not support that option as you can see at [this](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/v5.1.2/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_button.py#L352). But if you don't mind hack CustomTk, you can do like this.(It may not work in the future.)

```
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()

button = ctk.CTkButton(root, text='aaa bbb ccc ddd')
button._text_label.configure(wraplength=50)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

One edge case is if you initialize your button with no text, e.g.

```
button = ctk.CTkButton(root, text='')
```

Then button._text_label will be NoneType. You can get around this by initializing with some text, changing the wraplength, then running

```
button.configure(text='')
```

What about posting a feature request on [here](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues)?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I got it to work however the edges of the letters get cut off.
As shown here: https://imgur.com/a/TTrCx5V

Comment: Then set a smaller ```wraplength``` value. The ```wraplength``` is in pixels.

Comment: I dont know why I didn't think of that, thank you I got it to work perfectly now.